# how to run few ssh commands in batch?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

i want to run few commands in batch, one after one.
but the batch stop after 'killall firefox' with error, 'firefox no process found'.

what i need to do is:

1.kill firefox

2.clear memory

3.delete firefox profile

4.download my new profile

5.install unzip and unzip the profile

6.install xrdp

7.run firefox

my batch:

```
killall firefox && sync su echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && rm -r -f /root/.mozilla/ && wget -P /root/.mozilla/ https://www.dropbox.com/s/***/firefox.zip && sudo apt-get install unzip && unzip /root/.mozilla/firefox.zip -d /root/.mozilla/ && sudo apt-get install xrdp && firefox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue processing commands even after an error, separate the commands with `;` instead of `&&`.